# Using SQL Server CE in Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am trying to use SQL Server CE in windows service on Windows 2008.

Whenever I try to open connection to SQL Server CE database I get an error

> Database File not found

I am amazed because the database file is present there no issue with that part... any ideas?

> SQL Server Compact encountered problems when opening the database.
>   [ Internal Error Number = 25039, Internal Error String = Access to the database file is not allowed. [,,,File name,,] ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and in my case it was the location on the connection string.

I was putting only the database as data Source, like:

```
Data Source=Panoptes.sdf;
```

And I chenged for:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Panoptes.sdf;
```

After that it started to work normally

Comment: Yes you are right it was the ase with me... sorry to update answer.